# VSCode keyboard shortcuts don't work in all files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I'm editing .py files, certain keyboard shortcuts don't work. Copy, Cut, Paste, Indent `Ctrl+[]` and comment `Ctrl+/` to name a few. However, undo and redo work. I only experience this when working with .py files. I've looked in the keyboard shortcuts and afaik they are global shortcuts. I'm running Ubuntu 20.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Possible its because of the extension of the file, like if I am in a file.vue I use ctrl+shift+A to comment, but in a ruby file that same shortkey does another thing.

Try that in py files

Single line comment

Ctrl + 1

Multi-line comment select the lines to be commented

Ctrl + 4

Unblock Multi-line comment

Ctrl + 5